# HTTP/1.1 200 error while uploading documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, error

I was uploading documents on sharepoint using the drag and drop mechanism available on SharePoint, when google chrome crashed suddenly. I restarted google chrome and tried accessing sharepoint again but I'm getting the following error :

[image]

What can I do to make SharePoint work again?

Comment: Is it sharepoint online ?? have you tried closing browser and accessing again ?

Comment: Contact your administrator. May be application is deleted ? or It is not accessible . Ask them to check.

Comment: We restarted the services, there was an issue with the SharePoint Database. It is working fine now! Thank you for your response! :) Appreciate it.

Comment: You can write this and mark as Answer. So that people who will refer this will come to know. Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with the SharePoint Database. We restarted the services and the Database and it started working fine.

Comment: In one of your comments, you mentioned that its SharePoint Online, then how did you access the Database?